# Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'

Tags: java

I got this error in my android studio:

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```

Build.gradle(:app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "33.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0' }
        }
        applicationId "com.example.move_sensor"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

build.gradle(Mov_Sensor):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the error after building:

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```

AndriodMainifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.move_sensor">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Move_Sensor">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.move_sensor;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
////
        MovementDetector.getInstance().addListener(new MovementDetector.Listener() {



            @Override
            public void onMotionDetected(SensorEvent event, float acceleration) {

                TextView mMotionDetectionTextView = null;
                mMotionDetectionTextView.setText("Acceleration: ["+String.format("%.3f",event.values[0])+","+String.format("%.3f",event.values[1])+","+String.format("%.3f",event.values[2])+"] "+String.format("%.3f", acceleration));
                //if (acceleration > SettingsHelper.getInstance().getMotionDetectionThreshold()){
                //    mMotionDetectionTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
               // } else {
                    mMotionDetectionTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                //}

            }
        });
        ////
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MovementDetector.getInstance().start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        MovementDetector.getInstance().stop();
    }
    protected final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

after searching for it online I thought that decrease of the `dependencies`
to previouse version will fix that. so I changed my dependencies from:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

but I got similar error:

```
Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface</macro>'
```

any help with this?
thank you

Comment: still waiting for somebody to solve it.